# Remove empty class within an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some HTML on a page that looks like this (real example is hundreds of lines):

```
<h2 id="SectionA">Section A</h2>
<p class="Old-Formatting-Class">Some text here</p>
<p class="Another-Old-Formatting-Class" id="moreText">Some more text here</p>
```

Using javascript, I want to remove all classes from all paragraphs. Currently I am using:

```
Tag_Checklist = FooterDiv.querySelectorAll('p');
for (i = 0; i < Tag_Checklist.length; i++) {
    Tag_Checklist[i].className = "";
}
```

The problem I have is this leaves me with:

```
<h2 id="SectionA">Section A</h2>
<p class>Some text here</p>
<p class id="moreText">Some more text here</p>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<h2 id="SectionA">Section A</h2>
<p>Some text here</p>
<p id="moreText">Some more text here</p>
```

I was considering just doing a replace on the raw HTML to match `<p class` but that could cause other issues. Hoping to understand if this is something I can resolve with just DOM operations.

*Further context:* I am working on a web-based utility which reads in HTML, allows the user to update it via option buttons that perform various functions including this one, then saves the HTML. It does this by reading the HTML from file, then creating a new  on the page and setting it's innerHTML equal to the contents of the file. I can then make use of javascripts DOM manipulation in my code.

I am using the Chrome browser.

Comment: there u go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) to remove attribute from HTML element.

```js
Tag_Checklist = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for (i = 0; i < Tag_Checklist.length; i++) {
  Tag_Checklist[i].removeAttribute("class");
}
```

```html
<h2 id="SectionA">Section A</h2>
<p class="Old-Formatting-Class">Some text here</p>
<p class="Another-Old-Formatting-Class" id="moreText">Some more text here</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I need. 
I feel kinda dumb as I am using that elsewhere already!
*sigh*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute). Update code like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Tag_Checklist.length; i++) {
    Tag_Checklist[i].removeAttribute("class");
}
```